# how can I define an IP adress to my SAMA5D27 Board?

Tags: ip-address, embedded-linux, yocto

I m using SAMA5D27 SOM1 EK1 board, I build linux kernel image for it using yocto project, now the board is bootable.
My question is , how to define an IP adress for my board ? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you're using sysvinit, you can check the following manual [section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#customizing-a-recipe-for-a-bsp) on how to override interfaces file of `init-ifupdown` recipe

Comment: thank you for your interraction. To be honest with you i didn't understand well your solution. But while i was searching around I found this command " ifconfig " ,I connected my board to my pc and i tape the command. It shows an IP adress, is that the IP adress of my board ?

Comment: yes, you can check [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) how `/etc/network/interfaces` file set ip addresses. My previous message was about how to do some adjustments on that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ip address through the bootargs variable present in the u-boot environment variables.

Example:

bootargs = console = ttyS0,115200 ip = 192.168.0.116 ::::: eth0

The parameters present in the bootargs variable are passed to the kernel and configure their initialization, the advantage of opting for this method of ip address assignment is that the ip value is already changed  from the beginning of the boot process and not just when the ROOTFS takes over.

Comment: I was trying to open u-boot.env file with VIM command and NANO command on linux but that doesn't work with me. Any idea please ?

Comment: u-boot.env is a binary file and should not be edited, it should be built. It can be created through a text file, according to the tool implemented below:

https://bootlin.com/blog/mkenvimage-uboot-binary-env-generator/

Newer versions of u-boot allow insertion of environment variables into the u-boot.bin file itself, thus requiring no u-boot.env file. For this work mode the address of the .txt file must be assigned during compilation of u-boot through the menuconfig command.